# How to use class="active" in common header?

Tags: php, jquery

code: header.php

```
<?php 
    $page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    echo $page;
?>
<div class="nav-links"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav link-effect">
                    <li><a href="index.php" <?php if($page == 'index.php'){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php" <?php if($page == 'about.php'){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.php" <?php if($page == 'services.php'){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.php" <?php if($page == 'portfolio.php'){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="career.php" <?php if($page == 'career.php'){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Career</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

index.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

In this code I have created a common header file which is included in all files. Now, I want to use `class="active"` to know which menu is active. If I am using `class="active"` then only one menu is active for all files. So, How can I remove this problem? Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. In your 'header.php' file at top get the current page name by this:

```
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

By this you'll get current current page name.

Then change this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav link-effect">
  <li><a href="index.php" <?php if($page == 'one'){ echo ' class="active"';}?>>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php" <?php if($page == 'two'){ echo ' class="active"';}?>>About</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.php" <?php if($page == 'three'){ echo ' class="active"';}?>>Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="portfolio.php" <?php if($page == 'four'){ echo ' class="active"';}?>>Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="career.php" <?php if($page == 'five'){ echo ' class="active"';}?>>Career</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav link-effect">
   <li class="<?php if($page == 'index.php'){ echo ' active"';}?>"><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
   <li class="<?php if($page == 'about.php'){ echo ' active';}?>"><a href="about.php" >About</a></li>
   .... 

</ul>
```

> **UPDATE:**
>
> You are trying to add 'active' inside anchor tag. You need to add
>   active inside list tag.

Comment: I am simply include('header.php') in all inner pages

Comment: what not working? what is output? is there every <li> active or none of them are active?

Comment: try to echo '$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);' at any particular page. check if it's output is actual filename & not manipulate by .htaccess

Comment: Did you defined variable ($page) above your if statement? If you did then it should work.

Comment: Yes, @Nitish kumar sir I am define it.

Comment: sir please visit my editing code @Nitish kumar diwakar

Comment: I got it. instead of echoing 'class="active" ' use php quote inside class="<?php ?>". I've updated the answer. please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150452/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-diwakar-and-omkara).

Answer (score 0):

you could use javascript/jquery for it

```
    var url = $(location).attr('pathname');
```

depend on how you use href on 
navigation should use something in the following link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

```
    if (url != "/") {

        x = ".nav a[href^='" + x + "']";
        $(x).addClass('active');

        }
    else {
       $(".nav a[href^='/index.htm']").addClass('active');
    }
```

I don't do the full test on this code yet.